# How to check if a variable is undefined in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, environment-variables, httpd.conf

I know I can set a custom variable in `httpd.conf` to be accessed in `.htaccess`. I want to make my code fool proof so when it is set in a new machine by a new programmer, it won't get error easily.

How can I check undefined variable from the inside of `.htaccess` so it still can be run when someone forgets to set a variable in `httpd.conf`?

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond ${ServerBase} !^$
RewriteBase ${ServerBase}
```

I thought `!^$` can detect undefined variable, but nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In thing you want this :

```
<IfDefine ${ServerBase}>
...
</IfDefine >
```

Goto to Directive Define, documentation here : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html